# CSV with JSON columns

Tags: java, json, csv

I'm intending to have few of my columns in my dataset to be in JSON format, for grouping purposes, but the general CSV format is preserved (or whatever delimiter).

Is there a Java library that can process, parse, read, write CSVs that has columns as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any library that can do this. However, it is simple enough to use your go to CSV library, e.g. [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) and run the value string through [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

However, I would recommend using [JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org/) as a substitute for CSV. This can be parsed nicely out of the box with Jackson or Gson. You would end up with CSV like files like this:

```
["Name", "Session", "Score", "Completed", "some object"]
["Gilbert", "2013", 24, true, {"foo": "bar"}]
```